# What is the proper way for terminating tasks?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library

Have one question about right way to immediately task termination.
For example, I have the following code:

```
public async Task<string> DoAsync()
{
    var result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Some heavy request here in a row (5 seconds per request)
        DoHeavyRequest(); // 1
        DoHeavyRequest(); // 2
        DoHeavyRequest(); // 3
        DoHeavyRequest(); // 4

        return "success";
    });

    return results;
}
```

How I can cancel this task in one moment? For example, I run the task for 7 seconds, I expecting that only first and probably second "heavy requests" would be called, 3-4 will not be called at all.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource`, `CancellationToken`?

Comment: You cannot just terminate it. You should use cooperative cancellation with `CancellationToken` and friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *Cancellation*:

```
public async Task<string> DoAsync(CancellationToken token) {
  var result = await Task.Run(() =>  {
    //TODO: you may want to pass token to DoHeavyRequest() and cancel there as well
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    DoHeavyRequest(); // 1

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    DoHeavyRequest(); // 2

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    DoHeavyRequest(); // 3

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    DoHeavyRequest(); // 4

    return "success";
  });

  return "results";
}

// Let's preserve the current interface - call without cancellation
public async Task<string> DoAsync() {
  return await DoAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

...

```
// Run, wait up to 7 seconds then cancel 
try {
  using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource(7000)) {
    // Task completed, its result is in the result
    string result = await DoAsync(cts.Token);

    //TODO: Put relevant code here 
  }  
catch (TaskCanceledException) { 
  // Task has been cancelled (in this case by timeout)

  //TODO: Put relevant code here  
}
```